# Output spaces with uppercase array results

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, uppercase

Code is supposed to take the input for the size of the array and a set of characters and output them as uppercase. My problem is that when I input a sentence like "i love chocolate" its returning ILOVECHOCOLATE. Is the issue how I am grabbing the input? Or am I losing the spaces else where?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
void readString(char*, int);
void changeToUpper(char*, int);
void displayString(char*, int);
int main()
{
    int arraySize;
    char* characterArray;

    cout << "Enter the size of dynamic array: ";
    cin >> arraySize;
    characterArray = new char[arraySize];
    readString(characterArray, arraySize);
    changeToUpper(characterArray, arraySize);
    displayString(characterArray, arraySize);
    delete[] characterArray;
    system("pause");


    return 0;
}
void readString(char* characterArray, int arraySize){
    cout << "Enter a string of " << arraySize << " characters to be changed:";
    for(int i= 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        cin >> characterArray[i];
    }
}
void changeToUpper(char* characterArray, int arraySize){
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        characterArray[i] = toupper(characterArray[i]);
}
void displayString(char* characterArray, int arraySize){
cout << "\nYour string Upper Cased: ";
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    cout << characterArray[i];
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: `cin >>` generally skips whitespace although I am not sure if that remains true when you read one character at a time. That may be something to look at. `cin.get()` may be a better choice.

Comment: Or [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/).

Comment: That is what I saw when I looked online, but I haven't be able to add either of those without crashing the code. cin.getline(characterArray[i], arraySize); causes the error can't convert char to char * and cin.getline(characterArray, arraySize); doesn't bring letters back. Same thing with cin.get

Comment: Something like this might be what you're looking for. I assume this is an assignment since it would be much simpler to use `std::string` and `std::getline`. https://ideone.com/3PXxul

Comment: Thanks using characterArray[i] = cin.get(); works. I appreciate the help, and yes its an assignment. Which is half my problem. Code that works fine in visual studios doesn't pass the test process for my assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fgets` fucntion of `<csdio>` header file.

The parameter of this function is `char*` and `length including \0` and `FILE*`.

This function is finished only by `\n` character. You can include `whitespace` character.

But When u input a size of array, last character is `\n`. so u must clear that character.

`getc` function reads 1 character from `FILE stream`. By doing this, u skip `\n` happend from input of array size.

So these codes are changed.

```
#include <cstdio>    
cin >> arraySize; getc(stdin);

void readString(char* characterArray, int arraySize){
    cout << "Enter a string of " << arraySize << " characters to be changed:";
    fgets(characterArray, arraySize, stdin);
}
```